# Why is HttpClient.PostAsync() is not finished in Cosnole Application but finished in Web Application?

Tags: c#, web-applications, console-application, httpclient, threadpool

I used following code in console application,post calls are not finished until I use Console.Read(); at the end or client.PostAsync("api/xxx", contentPost).wait().
But in web application I dont have to use any wait() method . I dont want to use wait() method .Can some one help me with this issue .

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateLog();

    }
    private static void CreateLog()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        ProcessLog(new LogMessage() {
        });
        Console.Write("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    private static void ProcessLog(LogMessage message)
    {


        //Post message to web service
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        // ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("web api")
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"web api url");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
           new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                   
        HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client.PostAsync("api/xxx", contentPost);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You're counting on this to finish before the Console app does, but there are no guarantees (short of explicitly waiting for it) that that'll actually occur. In fact, with the code you have posted, you will *almost certainly* have numerous calls that haven't completed by the time that you get to the Console.Write() call.

The difference here is that your Console App will be terminated right after you press some key to enter. The Console.Read() is serving as a *de facto* Wait() call but there's absolutely no guarantee that a user will actually wait long enough for all of the calls to complete. Web applications have a completely different life cycle than Console applications do so they won't necessarily close as soon as you finish the calls.

You have to have some way of waiting for all of your calls to complete prior to exiting.

Comment: Yes.What is the solution for this problem ?And Console.Read() is a work around ,I don't want to use it .

Comment: You have to have some way of waiting for all of your calls to complete prior to exiting the application.

Comment: how to determine if there are some active calls ?

Comment: You have a few ways of doing this. In the example code you posted above, one possible solution would be to use a Parallel.For loop and have each of your actions wait for its respective reply.

Comment: See also the following article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/

Comment: Did this end up solving your problem?

Comment: Thanks for looking to this issue
No .If I use only  ProcessLog(new LogMessage() {}); without loops .How can I do it ?  I am looking for a way to find what are the active threads before console application exits ..